# How to install Elasticsearch plugins with docker container?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I have `3 elasticsearch-node` and `kibana` on my server in `docker-container` like this

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                    PORTS                                                 NAMES
0545e200fc43   docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.17.9                 "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   4 days ago   Up 43 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, :::5601->5601/tcp             ubuntu_kibana_1
d7ffcec877ae   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.9   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   4 days ago   Up 43 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                    ubuntu_es03_1
b68b45dde0c0   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.9   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   4 days ago   Up 43 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                    ubuntu_es02_1
24abbf05a06a   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.9   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   4 days ago   Up 43 minutes (healthy)   9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9400->9200/tcp, :::9400->9200/tcp   ubuntu_es01_1
```

now I want to install this `plugin` for `analysis-filter`

> bin\elasticsearch-plugin install https://www.dropbox.com/s/cr61dmnx95taivi/ParsiAnalyzer-7.13.1.zip?dl=1

how should I do that for my all 3 nodes?

**Update**

this is my `services-setup` config of my `docker-composer.yml` file

```
command: >
  bash -c '
    if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == ****** ]; then
      echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
      exit 1;
    elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == ****** ]; then
      echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
      exit 1;
    fi;
    if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
      echo "Creating CA";
      bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
      unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
    fi;
    if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
      echo "Creating certs";
      echo -ne \
      "instances:\n"\
      "  - name: es01\n"\
      "    dns:\n"\
      "      - es01\n"\
      "      - localhost\n"\
      "    ip:\n"\
      "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
      "  - name: es02\n"\
      "    dns:\n"\
      "      - es02\n"\
      "      - localhost\n"\
      "    ip:\n"\
      "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
      "  - name: es03\n"\
      "    dns:\n"\
      "      - es03\n"\
      "      - localhost\n"\
      "    ip:\n"\
      "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
      > config/certs/instances.yml;
      bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
      unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
    fi;
    echo "Setting file permissions"
    chown -R root:root config/certs;
    find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
    find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
    echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
    until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
    echo "Setting kibana_system password";
    until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:******" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"******\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
    echo "All done!";
  '
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install plugins in an ES container that i started using docker-compose. in the compose file i added commands such as `bash -c ./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ...`

Comment: I update my code, where should i put it?

Comment: in your dockerfile or docker-compose file, whatever you use.